# nodejs async await inside createReadStream

Tags: node.js, async-await, nodejs-stream

I am reading a CSV file line by line and inserting/updating in MongoDB. The expected output will be 
1. console.log(row);
2. console.log(cursor);
3.console.log("stream");

But getting output like
1. console.log(row);
 console.log(row); console.log(row); console.log(row); console.log(row); ............ ............
2. console.log(cursor);
3.console.log("stream");
Please let me know what i am missing here.

```
const csv = require('csv-parser');
const fs = require('fs');

var mongodb = require("mongodb");

var client = mongodb.MongoClient;
var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/";
var collection;
client.connect(url,{ useUnifiedTopology: true }, function (err, client) {

  var db = client.db("UKCompanies");
  collection = db.collection("company");
  startRead();
});
var cursor={};

async function insertRec(row){
  console.log(row);
  cursor = await collection.update({CompanyNumber:23}, row, {upsert: true});
  if(cursor){
    console.log(cursor);
  }else{
    console.log('not exist')
  }
  console.log("stream");
}



async function startRead() {
  fs.createReadStream('./data/inside/6.csv')
    .pipe(csv())
    .on('data', async (row) => {
      await insertRec(row);
    })
    .on('end', () => {
      console.log('CSV file successfully processed');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In your `startRead()` function, the `await insertRec()` does not stop more `data` events from flowing while the `insertRec()` is processing.   So, if you don't want the next `data` event to run until the `insertRec()` is done, you need to pause, then resume the stream.

```
async function startRead() {
  const stream = fs.createReadStream('./data/inside/6.csv')
    .pipe(csv())
    .on('data', async (row) => {
      try {
        stream.pause();
        await insertRec(row);
      } finally {
        stream.resume();
      }
    })
    .on('end', () => {
      console.log('CSV file successfully processed');
    });
}
```

FYI, you also need some error handling if `insertRec()` fails.

Comment: Thnks @jfriend00

Comment: stream pause/resume is very problematic and rarely works

Comment: @Pian0_M4n then what is the right solution?

Comment: @HungTran i haven't found a reliable way to stream with pause. Nothing I tried worked

Answer (score 6):

From **Node 10+** ReadableStream got property **Symbol.asyncIterator** and it's allow processing stream using **for-await-of**

```
async function startRead() {
    const readStream = fs.createReadStream('./data/inside/6.csv');    
    
    for await (const row of readStream.pipe(csv())) {
        await insertRec(row);
    }

    console.log('CSV file successfully processed');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That is expected behavior in this case because your `on` data listener triggers the `insertRec` asynchronously as and when data is available in stream. So that is why your first line of insert method is getting executed kind of in parallel. If you want to control this behavior you can use `highWaterMark` (https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_readablehighwatermark) property while creating the read stream. This way you will get 1 record at a time but I am not sure what your use case is.

something like this

```
fs.createReadStream(`somefile.csv`, {
  "highWaterMark": 1
})
```

Also you are not awaiting your `startRead` method. I would wrap it inside the promise and resolve it in `end` listener else you will not know when the processing got finished. Something like

```
function startRead() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.createReadStream(`somepath`)
      .pipe(csv())
      .on("data", async row => {
        await insertRec(row);
      })
      .on("error", err => {
        reject(err);
      })
      .on("end", () => {
        console.log("CSV file successfully processed");
        resolve();
      });
  });

}
```

Comment: Setting the highWaterMark does not let you throttle the rate of `data` events. The OP should instead implement a stream Writable that can be configured to `write` document-by-document, or `writev` a bulk of documents. The `highWaterMark` lets you control memory pressure.

Comment: @jorgenkg that is true. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @jorgenkg - "For streams operating in object mode, the highWaterMark specifies a total number of objects" - https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_buffering

Comment: Yes - the number of objects that will be buffered in the (read/write) stream's internal buffer. Objects will always be processed one at a time with `write`.The highWaterMark indicate how many objects that can be buffered for the stream instance.

Comment: Also in this example, the last result is not awaited as the "end" event will fire during its execution of "data" event handler. If the process were to now exit for example there would be data loss in that last record.